# Passing C++ objects by reference for participants in a simulated battle

Tags: c++, beginner, object-oriented, c++14, battle-simulation

I just started watching C++ videos couple of days ago. I tried taking everything I learned about classes and passing by references vs values. The main question I what would like to know is this the correct way to change the values of private class members or is there a more 'professional' way of doing it. (Or standard).

Entity.cpp:

```
void Entity::playerAttack(Entity &Player, Entity &Enemy) {
    cout << "\nPlayer is Attacking!" << endl;
    cout << "Enemy's health was at: " << Enemy.getHealth() << endl;
    totalHealth = Enemy.getHealth() - Player.getDamage();
    Enemy.setHealth(totalHealth);

    if (Enemy.getHealth() <= 0) {
        Enemy.setHealth(0);
        cout << "\nEnemies is 0 or below" << endl;
        cout << "Players health is at: " << Player.getHealth() << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Enemies health is now at: " << Enemy.getHealth() << endl;
    }
}

void Entity::setHealth(float x) {
    health = x;
}

void Entity::setDamage(float x) {
    damage = x;
}

float Entity::getDamage() {
    return (damage);
}

float Entity::getHealth() {
    return (health);
}
```

Entity.h:

```
#pragma once
class Entity
{
public:
    void setHealth(float x);
    void setDamage(float x);
    void playerAttack(Entity &Player, Entity &Enemy);
    float getHealth();
    float getDamage();

    Entity();
    ~Entity();

private:
    float health;
    float damage;
    float healAbility;
    float totalHealth;
};
```

source.cpp:

```
Entity constructE(float damage, float health, float regen) {
    Entity Entity;
    Entity.setDamage(damage);
    Entity.setHealth(health);
    Entity.setRegen(regen);

    return (Entity);
}

int main() {
    Entity Player = constructE(10, 100, 10);
    Entity Monster = constructE(5, 20, 5);
    Player.playerAttack(Player, Monster);
}
```

Comment: `return (damage);` What's the purpose of the parens??

Comment: Other programming languages require it so it's more of a habit and formatting style.

Comment: Have you tried to compile this, and does it compile, I see many things that should be flagged by the compiler as errors.

Comment: I have compiled it.

Comment: @Mvpg _"I have compiled it."_ [Sure?](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0f8ef13ef9b8a84d)

Comment: http://prntscr.com/esj48z Positive

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a couple of issues with how you are doing this (it is very Java like not C++ like).

#### Constructors

After the constructor finishes your object should be in a valid consistent state. Having to call multiple "setters" to finish initialization is a big red flag.

```
Entity constructE(float damage, float health, float regen) {
    Entity Entity;
    Entity.setDamage(damage);
    Entity.setHealth(health);
    Entity.setRegen(regen);

    return (Entity);
}
```

Why not just have a "constructor" that takes these arguments.

```
Entity Player = constructE(10, 100, 10);

// Should look like:
Entity Player(10, 100, 10);
```

#### Passing an object to itself?

```
Player.playerAttack(Player, Monster);
```

You are passing player as an argument? As you are calling a method on the object "player" you already have access to the player (via this). So there is no need to pass the player here.

```
player.attack(monster);
```

#### Identifier conventions.

One thing I notice about your code is that everything starts with a capitol letter. This makes it hard to tell the difference between types and objects. One of the most important things in C++ is type.

So the usual convention is that "User Defined Types" have an initial capitol letter. While objects (variables) have an initial lower case letter.

```
player.attack(monster);
^ Object      ^ Object
```

While:

```
Player.attack(monster);
|             ^ object
^ Looks like a type.
  So attack looks likes a static member function (ie a class method).
```

#### Getters/Setters

Getters and Setters break encapsulation. They expose the internal implementation details of the class. If you see the pattern

```
 auto x = object.getValue();
 auto y = performSomeAction(x);
 object.setValue(y);
```

Then this is usually an indication that you have not designed your class well as you expose internal details to calculate a value. A better design would be to provide a method that performs an ACTION on the class.

```
 object.someAction();   // internally it can update its own state.
```

#### Re-Design

```
class Entity
{
public:
     Entity(int damage, int helath, int regen)
         : damage(damage)
         , health(health)
         , healAbility(regen)
    {}
    // Destructor not needed.

    // Check if an entity is alive.
    operator bool() const
    {
        return health > 0;
    }
private:
    // Internal use only by attack()
    int weaponDamage() const
    {
        return myRandomNumber() % 10;  // Damage in the range 0..9
    }

    // Take damage
    Entity& takeDamage(int amount)
    {
        // Can not go below zero.
        health = max(0, health - amount);
        return *this;
    }
public:

    // Attack an Enemy
    void attack(Entity &enemy)
    {
        std::cout << "Player:     " << *this
                  << "Attacking:  " << enemy;

        // Damage the enemy and check if he is alive in one line.
        if (enemy.takeDamage(weaponDamage()) {
            // Enemy Alive
            cout << "E. Status: " << enemy;
        }
        else {
            // Enemy Dead
            cout << "Enemies is Dead" << "\n";
            cout << "P: Status: " << *this;
        }
    }

    virtual std::ostream& print(std::ostream& str) const
    {
        return str << "health: "       << health 
                   << " damage: "      << damage
                   << " healAbility: " << healAbility
                   << "\n";
    }
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& str, Entity const& data)
    {
        return data.print(str);
    }
private:

private:
    float health;
    float damage;
    float healAbility;
};
```

Comment: I'd suggest noting that rand() isn't reliable and should be avoided.

Comment: @Kodnot: So would I (if we wanted soething really random or cryptographically secure). But that's not part of the point I was trying to make and distracts for the correct discussion.

Comment: Although I do agree that proper randomness isn't really important here, I still believe that the subject should be informed. Ignoring such (small) mistakes / bad pieces of code can form bad habits, which are harder to get rid of later on. There is no need to give an in-depth explanation of the drawbacks of rand(), but I don't think that simply informing the subject that there are better alternatives would distract him from the correct discussion. (*Although now that I look at the code again, the subject didn't use randomness at all, so all this ranting of mine is pointless :P)